# Event studies: does test power depend on the window lenght?

Tags: time-series, statistical-power, finance

I am reading Cambell, Lo & MacKinlay ["The Econometrics of Fnancial Markets"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691043012/the-econometrics-of-financial-markets) (1996).
Chapter 4 covers event studies. Section 4.6 provides power analysis of tests discussed in section 4.4. These test are used to figure out whether the expected value $\mathbb{E}(R_{i,t})$ of returns on stocks, $R_{i,t}$, changes due to an event such as a stock split. ($i$ indexes firms, $t$ index time relative to the event.)

When presenting the setup of the power analysis on. p. 168-169, the authors do not seem to mention the sizes $L_1$ and $L_2$ of the estimation and event windows, respectively. The estimation window is a reference period from which expected values of future returns are estimated. The expected values are called *normal returns* and denoted. The event window is the period in which the expected values of returns may have changed due to the event. The actual values of returns less their expected values are called *abnormal returns* and denoted $\epsilon_{i,t}^*$. The null hypothesis of the tests is that the expected value of abnormal returns is zero, $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{i,t}^*)=0$. The two windows do not overlap.

Lack of reference to the length of the estimation and/or event windows, $L_1$ and $L_2$, in power analysis surprises me. Does the power of the tests not depend on any of them? After all, with an infinitely large estimation window ($L_1\rightarrow\infty$), our estimates of abnormal returns would be perfectly precise: $\hat\epsilon_{i,t}^*=\epsilon_{i,t}^*$. And with an infinitely large event window ($L_2\rightarrow\infty$), we would be able to estimate their expected value with perfect precision. Thus, a sensible test of the expected value being equal to zero would have power of 1.

What am I missing?

Comment: If anyone wishes to skim chapter 4 but does not have the book on their shelf, there is a pdf of the book out there in the wild...